# Error in Generating client library(Android) From Google app Engine(in Maven)

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am in the process of learning to create google-app-engine as well as to generate Endpoint client library(for Android) from my app-engine application.
So far I have done the following things

> Step 1 : Create Endpoint API : Complete

I have followed the instructions given here(using Maven) and have successfully deployed the  app-engine application

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/

> Step 2 : Generate Client Library(for Android) : Getting ERROR here

I have followed the instruction here
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients

I gave the following command from the root directory of my app-engine application

**endpoints.sh get-client-lib Greetings**

But getting the following error

```
Dec 16, 2013 5:47:43 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing ./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate /Users/raj/Documents/workspace-maven/helloendpoints/./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

Give below are my questions,

1. Is this command execution right?

   **endpoints.sh get-client-lib Greetings**

   In the documentation in google ; the second argument is
   specified as 'get-client-lib' I have given the same name while
   executing the command ; is this right?
2. As you can see in the error ; it describes ; file -
   **helloendpoints/./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml** could not be located.
   The file is indeed available in my application, but is located in a
   different directory(indeed in 3 locations) ; What should I do here?

   - ./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
   - ./target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
   - ./target/helloendpoints-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
3. The documentation suggest me to edit 'web.xml' file. But the file is
   available in 3 location and am not sure which one I have to edit(I
   have edited the file in 3rd location)

   - ./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
   - ./target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml
   - ./target/helloendpoints-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml

I am finding it quite difficult to resolve this issue ; as there is no other documentation (or) examples available in web other than the Google official documentation.

Would appreciate if some-one can help me to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to make sure that, you directory exist and that you have the required files into the directories. I can also use the maven goal to make the  generation, I read a complete article on the issue here. http://thenavigatorme.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-resolve-google-cloud-endpoints.html
Hope this helps.